# How do I access a DIV via its id attribute using jQuery.find()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I heed to access the Div with ID=rptMessages_ctl04_PanelComment , so that I can access the  DivLoadComments , to load HTML data....
By **.find()**  ??

```
<div class="ContainerClass">
    <div ID="**rptMessages_ctl04_PanelComment**">

        <div ID="DivLoadComments" class="ClassDivLoadComments">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) does not change, no matter which function you use. But you should have to use `.find()` to get an element by ID. This suggests that you have several elements with the same ID, which is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
$('#rptMessages_ctl04_PanelComment')
    .find('#DivLoadComments')
    .html('your html data');
```

Comment: you are welcome buddy.. dont forget to mark it as accepted answer for the help of future visitors.

Comment: oops... sorry.... will do dat !!!

sir, can u help me reslove  one more jquery issue  ?
I have posted a new question for the same....Its about unloading a page and all its child pages, dat are merged into the parent page , via jquery post using a DIV tag in parent ...
Only the main page gets unloaded , inner pages remain displayed...

Comment: pls give me the question link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600494/unload-inner-pages-called-by-jquery-post

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ContainerClass').find('#DivLoadComments')
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('#divId')
```

Answer (score 0):

More informations on what you exactly wnat to do would have been helpful... Well, to select a div by its ID you simply have to do `$("#id")` or `jQuery.find("#id")` ...