# Unload inner pages called by jquery post()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, post

My Contentpage is "**Mainpage.aspx**"   which gets data from "ProcessingPage.aspx" into a DIV tag of  **MainPage.aspx**  via **jquery post()** method.
But when I click to the ***Logout*** link from my **Master page**, then it uloads MainPage.aspx but displays **ProcessingPage.aspx**, which I want should also get unloaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can try removing `html` from the `div` in `MainPage.aspx` on logout. something like

```
$('#parent_div_id').html('');
```

It will remove all the `html` which was loaded from `ProcessingPage.aspx`